# Improve a ECG I am using an instrumentation amplifier

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier, ecg

I am doing an EMG as a part of my senior design project. I am currently using an Instrumentation amplifier but my professor suggested using a driven right-leg circuit. I was wondering how using a right-leg circuit would make it better (what are the benefits in filtering, speed, etc)?

He also asked me the following question: What is primary drawback to leaving a patient “floating” (i.e., not connected to the same voltage reference as the op-amp amplifier)? which I don't know how to answer. I thought that it was because the voltage difference could get dangerous, but it doesn't seem plausible.

Comment: By driving the right leg, does the voltage-difference become controlled?

Comment: I think what you professor is hinting, is the quality of your signal. A floating patient will pick up all sorts of electrical interference (noise). Especially 50/60Hz hum from the mains grid and florescent lighting. By driving the right leg you will reduce the effect of the noise.